# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object after login using laravel passport

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

hi i have build a  login system with laravel passport (personal acces token) so when i want to login and after to redirect to the home page it show me  "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" i know the source of error is when i delete construct  " $this->middleware('auth')"
he can't recover the name of authentificated user but when i put the construct the login can't redirect me to home page any solution guys:
this is my  currentUser.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

 const state ={
   user:{

    }

 };
  const getters= {};
 const actions = {
loginUser({},user){
   axios.post("/api/login",{
       email: user.email,

       password: user.password
   })
   .then(response=>{
       console.log(response.data);
      if( response.data.acces_token){
           //save token mte3na fi locoal storage
           localStorage.setItem(
               "membre_token",
               response.data.acces_token
           )

           window.location.replace("/home");
       }

   })
}
};
  const mutations={};

    export default{
    namespaced:true,
    state,
    getters,
     actions,
    mutations
     }

  and this is my web.php:

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
  });



 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
 Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any','.*');
```

and this is my home controller:

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class HomeController extends Controller
  {
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
  // $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{

    return view('home');
}
}
```

and this is my login router in api.php

```
Route::post('/login','API\AuthenController@login');
```

and this is my login function in AuthenController:

```
    public function login(Request $request){
 $validation=$this->validate($request,[
       'email'  =>'required|email',
       'password'=>'required',
      ])  ;

   if(!Auth::attempt($validation)){
       return response(['status'=>'error','message'=>'user Undefined']);
   }
 $accesToken =Auth::user()->createToken('TokenName')->accessToken;
 return response(['user'=>Auth::user(), 'acces_token'=>$accesToken]);
 }
```

Comment: Show the full error. I thing the error is not in your login code. Error has to come from where you are using something like $user->name (maybe it's in your blade file)

Comment: the error is when i delete $this->middleware('auth') from the home controller i can login but {{ Auth::user()->name}} in home blade can't be read it 
and when i put the $this->middleware('auth') in homeController construct to resolve the  {{ Auth::user()->name}}  i can't log in ??

Comment: vue.js uses api guard and blade uses web guard...

Comment: how can i fix it ??

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication